# Несколько полей для Count

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Имеется вот такой запрос

```
coordinates = Address.objects.filter(
    Q(created_date__gte=serializer.data['begin_date'])
    & Q(created_date__lte=serializer.data['end_date']),
    is_valid=True
).values('lat', 'lon')
```

Из которого я получаю данные в таком виде

```
<QuerySet [{'lat': 14.545, 'lon': 18.454}, {'lat': 14.545, 'lon': 18.454}, {'lat': 25.131, 'lon': 66.342}]>
```

Это координаты, широта и долгота, и они могут повторяться, как видно в примере
Как мне "схлопнуть" повторяющиеся значения и к ним добавить ещё ключ n, который будет указывать на кол-во повторений?

Comment: перебрать в цикле `QuerySet`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Результат должен получиться такой:

```
<QuerySet [{'lat': 14.545, 'lon': 18.454, 'n': 2}, {'lat': 25.131, 'lon': 66.342, 'n': 1}]>
```

Решение:

```
    coordinates = Address.objects.filter(
        Q(created_date__gte=serializer.data['begin_date'])
        & Q(created_date__lte=serializer.data['end_date']),
        is_valid=True
    ).values('lat', 'lon').annotate(
        n=Count(F('lat') + F('lon'))
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать следующую конструкцию:

```
from django.db.models import Count

coordinates = Address.objects.filter(
    Q(created_date__gte=serializer.data['begin_date'])
    & Q(created_date__lte=serializer.data['end_date']),
    is_valid=True
).values('lat', 'lon').annotate(Count('lat'), Count('lon'))
```